# put OBJ files in subdirectory in MAKEFILE

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My basic Makefile create the .o without the need of writing a line with gcc:

```
NAME = libtest.h
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I. -c
SRCS = example01.c \
       example02.c
OBJ = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

all: $(NAME)
$(NAME): $(OBJ)
       ar -rc $@ $<
```

I suppose that the rule `$(SRCS:.c=.o)` is making an equivalent as running `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<` because I didn't need to call for the compiler explicitly?

But then when I try to do the same with the add of a subdirectory in which goes the OBJ files it doesn't work:

```
NAME = libtest.h
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I. -c
SRCS = example01.c \
       example02.c
ODIR = ./builds
OBJ = $(addprefix $(ODIR)/, $(SRCS:.c=.o))

all: $(NAME)
$(NAME): $(OBJ)
       ar -rc $@ $<
```

The subdirectory already exist in this example of course. The error output is : `No rule to make target 'builds/example01.o', needed by 'libtest.a'`
I saw solutions that both explicitly call the compiler and have the rule `$(SRCS:.c=.o)` but I feel like it calls for the compiler two times with no need then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

> I suppose that the rule $(SRCS:.c=.o) is making an equivalent as running $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

is not quite right.  Make has a suite of [built-in pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) it can apply if you don't define your own rule.  One of these tells it how to build a `foo.o` file from a `foo.c` file.

But make has no built-in rule telling it how to build a `./builds/foo.o` file from a `foo.c` file, so you have to supply that yourself:

```
$(ODIR)/%.o : %.c
         $(COMPILE.c) -o $@ $<
```

(this uses a built-in variable `COMPILE.c` which is what the built-in rule uses; of course you can define your own).

Comment: perfect ! little precision : thanks to COMPILE.c I don't need to put the -c option in CFLAGS (for what i got), because COMPILE.c already compile with -c

Comment: It's something of an anti-pattern to put `-c` into `CFLAGS`, because `CFLAGS` can be used in places where you don't want to generate an object file.  For example, it's common to include `CFLAGS` on the linker line as well to get all the same optimization, warning, threading, C standard selection, etc. at link time as you do compile time.